# how to customize Show History eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse -> Show history option gives capability to search particulate history based on criteria like author, comment, date etc. I want to reuse that Search SVN History plugin (`HistorySearchDialog.java` in `org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui_1.6.18.jar`)

Any idea how I can reuse eclipse inbuilt plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you can use by eclipse plug-in development.
You can customize eclipse plug-in as per your need.

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html
- http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html

after the above articles , you need to check Fragmantation in eclipse as well.